# Can I use other voices than »standard« and »wavenet« for Dialogflow within Twilio?

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, text-to-speech

I am new to programming voice agents with Twilio and Dialogflow. I have an agent up and running with Twilio Studio at them moment. It uses the Dialogflow integration, but I am not happy with the voices available for text-to-speech (TTS) within Twilio.

I can choose some nice voices for the »say« widget, but these voices are not available for the »Dialogflow« widget, which only seems to support »standard« and »wavenet« voices.

Is it possible to use better voices within Twilio for the TTS of the Dialogflow integration?

[image: Voice configuration of the Dialogflow connector]